# How to display a single form with Foreign Key and choices in a Django Form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

My goal is display a form with all theses fields, I'm stuck to display city and description field from **City** model, the first one needs to display a select box with all cities choices and the other just a text field.

So, I need to display a form with this format:

- city (With selected box from all choices)
- description
- date
- status

  ```
  CITIES_CHOICES = (('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'), ('NY', 'New York'), ('PIT', 'Pittsburgh'))


   class City(models.Model):
       city = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CITIES_CHOICES)                    
       description = models.TextField()

       def __str__(self):
           return self.city


    class Checkin(models.Model):
       destination = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
       date = models.DateTimeField()
       status = models.BooleanField()
  ```

I had create a form using Modelform but how can I display the fields from City model instead display de city object properly?

Any idea where I need to go now?

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Checkin
```

Answer (score 1):

There a few ways to go about this. One of the easier ways would be to create two forms, a `ModelForm` for `City` and a `ModelForm` for `Checkin`. Inside the view, you can pass both forms to the context and validate both forms. You can load them inside the same form tag on the HTML page.

I would not include the "city" field inside the `Checkin` form, you can handle this manually inside the view.

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        city_form = CityForm()
        Checkin_form = CheckInForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        city_form = CityForm(request.POST)
        checkin_form = CheckInForm(request.POST)
        if city_form.is_valid() and checkin_form.is_valid():
            city = city_form.save()
            date = checkin_form.cleaned_data.get('date')
            status = checkin_form.cleaned_data.get('status')
            Checkin.objects.create(
                destination=city,
                date=date,
                status=status
            )

    context = {
        'city_form': city_form,
        'checkin_form': checkin_form,
    }
    return render(request, <template>, context)
```

This is a quick example, you could create this in a single form or even through an API if you wanted. I think it would be better in a Class Based View as well.